# How to pass data of table row from one component to another component

Tags: html, angular, typescript, angular-material

I have using mat-table(Angular Materials) on my one component and after clicking on particular row that data in TR should be displayed to another component. Entire information is in "row" parameter

And how I can print it on my new component page.

I had tried many ways to do this, but not able to print in another component.

My first Component HTML

```
<section class="example-container mat-elevation-z8" tabindex="0" >
        <table mat-table [dataSource]="tiffinMenu1">

          <ng-container matColumnDef="item">
            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> ITEM </th>
            <td mat-cell matRipple *matCellDef="let tiffinOne" ngDefaultControl > {{tiffinOne.item}} </td> //THIS IS THE DATA TO BE PRINTED ON ANOTHER COMPONENT AFTER CLICK ///
          </ng-container>

          <ng-container matColumnDef="price">
            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> PRICE </th>
            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let tiffinOne"> {{tiffinOne.price}} </td>
          </ng-container>

          <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns; sticky: true"></tr>
          <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>

        </table>
      </section>
```

this is my Second component HTML

```
<div class="split right">
    <div class="centered">
        <p>Token Number: 02</p>
    </div>

    <p>Working:</p>

// here want to display {{tiffinOne.item}} & {{tiffinOne.price}} which is from another component

    <button>Print</button>
    <button>Cancel</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi welcome to Stack Overflow. How will be your design for your requirement? When clicking the item, it should be redirected to new page? Or are the table and details components in the same page? The design will affect how you pass the data between components.

Comment: its on same page, but different component and here table and details are in different component. 
Actually, I have to click the data in first component and it should be reflected in the second component. (PS: The  data in table is connected to database and no Hardcode is done in the TS file) please help me out @YongShun

Answer (score 0):

I think it can be achieved this way:

1. Add a click event handler to `<tr mat-row...` and pass current row (let row) to this handler
2. In this handler store the clicked row in a component's public field like `this.selectedRow = row`
3. Bind your second component to selectedRow